# Google map not registered on click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, click

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.zedfox.us/make-20km-radius-buffer-around-point-google-maps/) to create a circle upon map on click event. Here is the initialization of the map under `tab1.js`:

```
function initMap() {
    forecastmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('forecastmap'), {
      center: {lat: 1.352083, lng: 103.81983600000001},
      zoom: 11
    });
    forecastmap.addListener('click', function(e) {
        createBuffer(e.latLng, forecastmap);
    });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
```

Then inside my `tab2.js` where I perform all the logic to add the markers:

```
function createBuffer(coord, forecastmap) {
    console.log('come in');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coord,
        map: forecastmap
    });
    clusterData.push(marker);

    marker = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: coord,
        map: forecastmap,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        fillColor: '#f0f0f0',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 20 * 1000
    });
    clusterData.push(marker);
}
```

I inserted a dummy message to check if the click event is registered. However, the message did not even printed out. I wonder which part of the code was wrong.

My HTML div:

```
<div class="box-body">

                                      <div id="forecastmap" style="width:100%;height:350px" onclick="initMap();"></div>


                                </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for `addEventListener` as opposed to `addListener`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge  
I tried to search from here: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events But I don't see any addEventListener. Do you mind to provide me with the syntax? Because I changed the above to addEventListener and it tells me the function is not defined

Comment: `addEventListener` is the [**raw JavaScript method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). I don't use Google Maps myself, but there's apparently a Google one `addDomListener` : `google.maps.event.addDomListener`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I tried with the addDomListener but strangely it does not work as well.

Comment: Down voter mind to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `addListener` is not a valid method, and you're either looking for the native **[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**, or Google's **[`addDomListener()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener)**.

I'm not too familiar with Google Maps, but considering the map is generated dynamically, the `forecastmap` variable may not available on page load. As such, you'll need to hoist the scope to an element that is available on page load, and make use of **[event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)**.

Instead of:

```
forecastmap.addListener('click', function(e) {
    createBuffer(e.latLng, forecastmap);
});
```

You probably need something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Check that the click target is #forecastmap
  if (e.target && e.target.id == "forecastmap") {
    createBuffer(e.latLng, forecastmap);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey sorry but where do I put the second chunk of the code? Inside the initMap() as well? But the strange thing is I managed to plot all markers onto the map, and able to click on the marker item to show info window, just that when I click on the map, it does not return me the dummy message

Answer (score 0):

You have a click listener on the map div (the div with id="forecastmap"), that calls the `initMap()` function (`onclick="initMap()"`), recreating the map, losing any circle you may have added.  If I remove that, and add a `google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(document.getElementById("forecastmap"), ...` that initialized the map on the first click (only), then I get markers and circles.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy1g02zh/2/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var forecastmap;

function initMap() {
  forecastmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('forecastmap'), {
    center: {
      lat: 1.352083,
      lng: 103.81983600000001
    },
    zoom: 11
  });
  forecastmap.addListener('click', function(e) {
    createBuffer(e.latLng, forecastmap);
  });

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(document.getElementById('forecastmap'), "click", initMap);
// });

function createBuffer(coord, forecastmap) {
  console.log('come in');
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord,
    map: forecastmap
  });
  // clusterData.push(marker);

  marker = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: coord,
    map: forecastmap,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    fillColor: '#f0f0f0',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 20 * 1000
  });
  // clusterData.push(marker);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#forecastmap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div id="forecastmap" style="width:100%;height:350px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm but I am getting this error message:Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at the addDomListener there

Comment: That is a different problem.  You didn't include the load of the API in your question. Load it the same way as done in the answer.

Comment: But the map in jsfiddle does not show up until the first click. Is there any way to register the click event upon loading the map?